# Putting a menu bar on the bottom of the screen while using ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I figured out how to get the menu bar on top of the screen.  It stays in position while I move around the main menu I created using expandableListView.  However, I would like the menu bar to be on the bottom of the screen instead of the top.  I played around with relativeView and got the bar on the bottom, however, the main menu disappears. 
Here is my main xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonbefore"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="back" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonnext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="Next" />
</LinearLayout>

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/main_no_items" />
```

Then I used this for java to get it to appear in my program.

```
   LinearLayout bottomMenu = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.buttons);
```

I tried playing around with the gravity and it did nothing.  I can add more code from my program if you think it will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your `buttons` LinearLayout is the 'menu bar' you're referring to?

You can actually accomplish what you're looking for using either a RelativeLayout or a LinearLayout.

**LinearLayout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="@string/main_no_items" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonbefore"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="back" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonnext"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Next" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The buttons are bottom-aligned by setting the gravity, while the list is told to take up all other available space by giving it a weight of '1' and setting a height of '0dp'. That will cause it to stretch as much as possible without pushing the buttons off-screen.

**RelativeLayout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttons"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="@string/main_no_items" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonbefore"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="back" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonnext"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Next" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The buttons are bottom-aligned by setting the alignment on the parent. The list is told to fill all height, but stay 'above' the buttons.

On a general note: in order for this to work, I'm pretty sure that the list and empty views need to be combined together in their own layout.

Comment: Thanks, I needed to add another LinearLayout and put the buttons as the second LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

The way to align the buttons to the bottom is to change your top level LinearLayout into a RelativeLayout. Then you can add the attribute `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to your LinearLayout `@+id/buttons`, which holds your two buttons.